# Proving $e^{\sqrt{z}}$ is not holomorphic in certain points

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

It is known that $e^{\sqrt{z}}$, with the branch cut $[-\pi,\pi)$ is continuous on points of the form $-c+0i$, where $c=(k\pi)^2, k\in\mathbb{Z}$. This is because $\sqrt{z}$ "is either" $k\pi i$ or $-k\pi i$, and exponential of both values coincide. I was trying to prove that this function is $\textbf{not}$ holomorphic in these points using only basic complex analysis. With this I mean analyzing different limits, Cauchy Riemann or similar. I was not able to reach a contradiction, so I would greatly appreciate some help.

Comment: Yes @MartinR, I can

Comment: If a function is holomorphic at a point, then is it necessarily continuous at a neighbourhood of it?

Comment: The limit of $\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}$ exists

Comment: I have tried to answer your question. Please let me know if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is not holomorphic at the points $-(k\pi)^2$ because it is not even continuous in a neighborhood of those points. Quoting from [Holomorphic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function):

> The phrase "holomorphic at a point $z_0$" means not just differentiable at $z_0$, but differentiable everywhere within some neighbourhood of $z_0$ in the complex plane.

But $f$ is not even complex differentiable at the points $ -(k\pi)^2$, i.e. the limit $\frac{f(z)-f(z_k)}{z-z_k}$ does not exists for $z_k = -(k\pi)^2$, $k=1, 2, 3, \ldots$.

This can be seen as follows: Write $f(z) = e^{s(z)}$ where $s(z)$ is the complex square root of $z$ with $-\pi/2 \le \arg s(z) < \pi/2$. First show that the limit
$$
 \lim_{\substack{h \to 0 \\ \operatorname{Im} h \le 0}} \frac{s(z_k+h) - s(z_k)}{h} = \frac{1}{2s(z_k)} = \frac{1}{-2k\pi i}
$$
exists for all $k$. It follows that
$$ \tag{$*$}
 \lim_{\substack{h \to 0 \\ \operatorname{Im} h \le 0}} \frac{f(z_k+h) - f(z_k)}{h} = \frac{e^{s(z_k)}}{2s(z_k)} = \frac{1}{2k\pi i}
$$
for all $k$.

For $h$ with positive real part is $s(z_k+h) = \overline{s(z_k+\bar h)}$ and consequently $f(z_k+h) = \overline{f(z_k+\bar h)}$. Also $f(z_k) = -1 = \overline{f(z_k)}$. It follows that
$$
 \frac{f(z_k+h)-f(z_k)}{h} = \frac{\overline{f(z_k+\bar h)}-\overline{f(z_k)}}{h}
= \overline{\left( \frac{f(z_k+\bar h)-f(z_k)}{\bar h}\right)}
$$
and therefore
$$ \tag{$**$}
\lim_{\substack{h \to 0 \\ \operatorname{Im} h > 0}} \frac{f(z_k+h) - f(z_k)}{h} = \overline{\lim_{\substack{h \to 0 \\ \operatorname{Im} h < 0}} \frac{f(z_k+h) - f(z_k)}{h}} = -\frac{1}{2k\pi i}
$$
The limits $(*)$ and $(**)$ are different, so that $f$ is not complex differentiable at $z_k$.